# Cucumber Transforms across files

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, transform

I have two transforms in features/support/transforms/date_transform.rb

```
CAPTURE_YEAR = Transform /^(20\d{2})$/ do |year|
  year.to_i
end

CAPTURE_QUARTER = Transform /^(first|second|third|fourth)$/ do |quarter|
    {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}[quarter.to_sym]
end
```

I have another transform in features/support/transforms/number_transform.rb

```
CAPTURE_NUMBER = Transform /^\d+$/ do |number|
  number.to_i
end
```

I realize that the year and the number ones are nearly identical, but I don't want to simply rid the `CAPTURE_YEAR` variable. I'd like to do:

```
CAPTURE_YEAR = CAPTURE_NUMBER
```

But unfortunately, `CAPTURE_NUMBER` doesn't exist in the file I'm working with. Any idea how to include other transforms correctly in cucumber? I should have to explicitly require the file from each transform file right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cucumber just loads up whatever files are in the `support` directory.  It seems to load them in alphabetical order (but I don't know that this is a documented/reliable behaviour - i.e. I wouldn't like to just rename the files to get around it).

If you're trying to declare `CAPTURE_YEAR` before the file containing `CAPTURE_NUMBER` has been loaded, then it will fail, as you've discovered.

I think your best option is to explicitly require the `number_transform` file before trying to use constants declared inside it.  Personally I don't have a problem declaring, within a file, which files it's dependent on.

You could also require it inside `env.rb`, as this gets parsed before any of the other support files, and might be a better option if many of your other files depend on it as well.